# Assigning "escape" key to a button in windows form in C#

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a simple windows form in C#. my form has a bottun which in Click event is several codes and tasks.

i want to assign escape key on keyboard to this button. how can i do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set `KeyPreview = true;` for the form and then override form's `OnKeyDown` method something like this:

```
protected override void OnKeyDown(KeyEventArgs e)
{
    base.OnKeyDown(e);

    if (e.Modifiers == Keys.None && e.KeyCode == Keys.Escape)
        //your button click event handler call here like button1_Click(null, null);
}
```

Comment: This is for any-key case. For ESC, the normal solution is the answer from Fratyx below.

Comment: As from OP's comment to Fratyx's answer - he wants handle not only ESC button ;)

Comment: i did what you said. bu idon't know why it dosn't work same as cliking by mouse.                                            private void BtnCancel_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnKeyDown(e);
            if (e.Modifiers == Keys.None && e.KeyCode == Keys.Escape) ;
            BtnCancel_Click(null,null);
        }

Comment: @Behnam You shouldn't create private BtnCancel_KeyDown method. Just do **exactly** what I've wrote - set `KeyPreview = true` property of your form and **override** `OnKeyDown` method of **form**.

Answer (score 3):

Your form has a property `CancelButton`. Assign your button to this property. You can easily do that in property window of Visual Studio. Then your button will be clicked when hitting escape.

Comment: thank you so much. can you help me about other keys like "+" or "-"

Comment: @Behnam see solution suggested by me. It fits any keys you want - just include another condition under `e.KeyCode`

Comment: @Behnam: This works just for frequently used dialog keys as Esc and ENTER (`AcceptButton`). For general purpose use the KeyCode solution.